# collapse/expand nested tables using jquery

Tags: jquery, html

I have requrement to collapse/expand nested tables using jquery (Parent,child,grand child etc).

1. Initially all parents will be collapsed.
2. When click a parents its child only exapnd.

Please look at my jsfiddle

http://jsfiddle.net/vivekcek/36SRa/

```
   <table border="1">
<thead>
    <tr>
        <td></td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
        <td>Header</td>
    </tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td><a href="#">[+]</a></td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>
        <td>Data</td>

    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td colspan="5">
            <table border="1">
                <tbody>
                    <tr class="parent">
                        <td><a href="#">[+]</a></td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="child">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <table border="1">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td><a href="#">[+]</a></td>
                                        <td>Data</td>
                                        <td>Data</td>
                                        <td>Data</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="child">
                                        <td colspan="4">
                                            <table border="1">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="parent">
                                        <td><a href="#">[+]</a></td>
                                        <td>Data</td>
                                        <td>Data</td>
                                        <td>Data</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr class="child">
                                        <td colspan="4">
                                            <table border="1">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="parent">
                        <td><a href="#">[+]</a></td>
                        <td>Data</td>
                    </tr>
                    <tr class="child">
                        <td colspan="2">
                            <table border="1">
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td>[+]</td>
                                        <td>Data</td>
                                        <td>Data</td>
                                        <td>Data</td>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td colspan="4">
                                            <table border="1">
                                                <thead>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                        <td>Header</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </thead>
                                                <tbody>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                    <tr>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                        <td>Data</td>
                                                    </tr>
                                                </tbody>
                                            </table>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </td>
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </td>
    </tr>

</tbody>
```

I am using jquery like this

```
  <script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function () {

    function getChildren($row) {
        var children = [];
        while ($row.next().hasClass('child')) {
            children.push($row.next());
            $row = $row.next();
        }
        return children;
    }

    $('.parent').on('click', function () {

        var children = getChildren($(this));
        $.each(children, function () {
            $(this).toggle();
        })
    });

    $.each($('.parent'), function () {

        var children = getChildren($(this));
        $.each(children, function () {
            $(this).toggle();
        })

    });

})
```

Comment: What's the question? It appears as though you're asking us to write code for you. You'll need to try it yourself, first.

Comment: Can you please do some research into this and try it for yourself, we are happy to help when you have a problem that you have tried for yourself but are reluctant to do all of the work for you.

Comment: I am not familiar with jquery, can you help me how to handle this with class, id and jquery.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

To hide all tables apart from the very parent table you can use:

`$('table table').hide();`

To show/hide the child table of the clicked anchor you can do the following:

```
$('td > a').on('click', function(e) {
  e.preventDefault(); // prevents the link from being followed
  $(this).closest('tr').next().find('table:first').toggle();
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/36SRa/15/)

Comment: Thank you, but when i click last child its parent is opening,

Comment: @VivekPoomala something like [this](http://jsfiddle.net/36SRa/22/)?

Comment: Wow great. One more help. when one [+] is clicked all other expanded should collapse and only the clicked ones child should be visible

Comment: But when we use in an actual page with tables and td, which script may applicable for that too. How can i make this work with some Id or css class

Comment: @VivekPoomala [Here's an example using classes](http://jsfiddle.net/MQsMt/8/)

Comment: But when i tried in visual studio all table are exapnded when load. but in jsfiddle same is collapsed initially

Comment: i think something with document ready..working fine in jsfiddle. But when come to visual studio MVC all table are expanded but once you click [+] clopse working fine

Comment: at the last example you missed a clossing table tag

Comment: @VivekPoomala I copy/pasted the code from your question :p

Comment: @billyonecan- Thanx a lot, i copied your last jsfiddle and tried still the first time all expanded in browser but in jsfiddle same works fine

Comment: this is latest fiddle http://jsfiddle.net/vivekcek/vG26J/ Working fine in fiddle initially all collapsed. But in real browser MVC i try. all are expanded